# Rate equation of first law of thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics

The mathematical expression for first law of thermodynamics is:

$\delta{Q} = dE + \delta{W}$

here E is the total stored energy of the system

One of my book mentions that, we consider a time interval $\delta{t}$ during which amount of heat $\delta{Q}$ crosses the control surface and an amount of work $\delta{W}$ is done by the control mass

So dividing the initial equation by $\delta{t}$, we get

$\frac{\delta{Q}}{\delta{t}} = \frac{dE}{\delta{t}} +\frac{\delta{W}}{\delta{t}}$

Taking limit for each of these quantities at $\delta{t}$ approaches Zero, we have

$\lim_{\delta{t}\to 0 }\frac{\delta{Q}}{\delta{t}} = \lim_{\delta{t}\to 0 } \frac{dE}{\delta{t}} + \lim_{\delta{t}\to 0 } \frac{\delta{W}}{\delta{t}}$

$\implies \frac{dQ}{dt} = \frac{dE}{dt} + \frac{dW}{dt}$

$\therefore \dot{Q} = \dot{\frac{dE}{dt}} + \dot{W}$

My question, how can we assume $\delta{t}$ isn't $\delta$ used for path dependent variable? Is time path dependent then? and what is going on after we take the limits,how does $\delta $ changes to $d$

Comment: How would time be path dependent?

Comment: @BioPhysicist that's my point! how can we use $\delta$ with time?

Comment: Mathematical issues aside, the rate of change in internal energy equals the rate of heat transfer to/from the system minus the rate of work done by/on the system. Or, simply, $\Delta \dot U=\dot Q - \dot W$.

Comment: @BobD I am seeking an mathematical interpretation

Comment: @AbhilekhGautam My differential calculus is not strong, but the problem may lie in the meaning of $\delta$ for heat and work. It is neither an exact differential nor a partial differential. It does not mean "change" as in change of value, because heat and work are not state properties but rather transfers of energy. So $\delta$ in these cases means the "amount" of work done or heat transfer and not the "change" in heat or work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\dot q$ is the heating from the outside across the system boundary, $\dot w$ is the external work done by the system on the environment. Both $\dot q$ and $\dot w$ are directly measurable quantities that have no direct relationship to the so-called state variables of the system that absorbs the working (work rate) and heating ("heat" rate). When, say, $\dot q$ is integrated over time we get a finite amount of "heat" absorbed by the system, $\Delta  Q = \int_{t_0}^{t_1}\dot q dt$ but here $\dot q$ is only function of $time$ and of nothing else.

The 1st law can indeed be written as $\dot q = \frac{dE}{dt} + \dot w$ where $E$ is *the* internal energy of the system and Truesdell and his followers always do it this way; see the subject under the heading *Rational Thermodynamics*.

In fact, writing the 1st law in the differential (or better said *infinitesimal*) form as $\delta q = dE + \delta w$ is just a tacit acknowledgment that the fundamental quantities are heating not "heat", or working not "work". Of course  if you prefer infinitesimals then you can always write it equivalently using $\delta q = \dot q dt$ or $\delta w =\dot w dt$.
(The real fun starts when you combine the 1st law in the rate equation form with the 2nd law of thermodynamics in its rate equation form ...)